# Что за ошибка с парсингом ссылки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Если 22 строку закомментить, то все отлично работает, как только убираю коментарий, возникает ошибка "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ",
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;'
    }
HOST = 'https"//auto.ria.com'
def get_html(url,params= None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers = HEADERS, params = params)
    return r
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='unlink rotator5_item')
    price = soup.find_all('span',class_='price')
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title':item.find('li',class_='title').get_text(strip=True),
            'price':item.find('span',class_='price').get_text(strip=True),
            #'link':HOST +item.find('a',class_='unlink rotator5_item').get('href'),
            })
    print(cars)
def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        print("Все круто")
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Все плохо,давай по новой Миша")
parse()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает:

```
cars.append({
    'title': item.find('li', class_='title').get_text(strip=True),
    'price': item.find('span', class_='price').get_text(strip=True),
    'link': item.find('a', class_='unlink rotator5_item')
    })
```

Проблема в том, что метод возвращает `None`, в котором нет метода `.get()`. Из-за проблемы с трейс-бэком.